# Joomla sitemap generation time out because sitemaps are too big

Tags: joomla, sitemap

Our Joomla news site has many thousands of articles for years. I bought a module responsible for generating sitemaps but cant generate the map as it gives me site time-out I think because sitemap is too big. I increased time-out of the server with no luck. Any solutions for that?

Answer (score 0):

You can always create different sitemaps for your whole site. Anyway, Google only allows up to 50.000 urls in a sitemaps.xml. Check [Google webmaster guidelines](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/183668?hl=en&topic=8476&ctx=topic).
After that you just have to add all of them to Webmaster Tools.

Don't know what extension have you used but there are several nice ones:
[OsMap](http://extensions.joomla.org/profile/extension/structure-a-navigation/site-map/osmap) (free) or [JSitemap](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/jsitemap) (paid).

Answer (score 0):

Try breaking your sitemaps into smaller sitemaps and then organizing a list of those sitemaps in a sitemap index.

http://snipref.com/webmaster/how-many-pages-should-a-large-sitemap-have/